# "animationend" does not fire sometimes

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I have a CSS animation that gets applied to a HTML element with a CSS class. I also have an event listener attached to the `animationend` (it's a modern Windows app so the browser is IE11 only). What I'm seeing is that *sometimes* the event gets fired and sometimes it doesn't. Regardless of the event firing I can always see it visually animating. It looks like some kind of race condition to me.

I have searched the web trying to understand what could cause this event to not get fired but I haven't found any satisfying results. I found the following on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions):

> Note: The transitionend event doesn't fire if the transition is aborted because the animating property's value is changed before the transition is completed.

**UPDATE1:** `transitionend` has nothing to do with `animationend` so this info is unrelated.

I'm not sure if the same is applicable for CSS animations. Does anyone have any ideas as to what can cause this? If there was any event that could detect that an animation was aborted that could also be a useful workaround.

**UPDATE2:** The current workaround that I'm using:

```
element.addEventListener("animationstart", function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        // do stuff
    }, animationDuration);
});
```

Comment: Nothing immediately comes to mind, but I know that `animationend` is *different* than `transitionend`.

`transitionend` event is for CSS transitions, using the `transition` CSS property. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transition

`animationend` event is for CSS animations, using `keyframes` and the `animation` CSS property. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation

So perhaps this might help you out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnimationEvent

Comment: That's what I thought. I'm using `keyframes` and `animation`. No transitions.

Comment: Are you using `animation-iteration-count: infinite;`? I don't have a windows machine to test IE11, but on chrome, `animation-iteration-count: infinite;` will not fire an `animationend` event.

Comment: I don't have `animation-iteration-count` specified on my css class, but I would assume if that defaulted to `infinite`, I would not get `animationend` ever.

Comment: On chrome it defaults to 1... Does your animation loop?

Comment: No, it does not. Here is the scenario: I have the animation to fade the element away in a specific way. When animation is done, I remove it from the DOM. Then the next element gets added. This animation happens multiple times, but never repeats on the same element.

Comment: You'll need to post more code to help me reproduce it. http://jsfiddle.net/sdcsmbo6/ works for me, on IE11.

Comment: Have you found any solution ? I'm facing similar issue if I click a button too fast the transitionend sometimes does not fire.

Comment: I've had similar issues. You should make sure there are no other events happening that will trigger layout and repaint. What happens is that the animation gets interrupted (from scrolling for example) and the event never fires. In my case I implemented a simple timeout that gets cleared if the animationend event fires. Or ... it does the same stuff that the animationend event had to do.

Comment: give us full code

Comment: Do you have a [mcve] that we can look at?

Comment: As you can see, the question was asked 3 years ago. I don't have a repro environment for this issue at the moment, sorry.

Comment: Sometimes this event will not fire at all - page resize, DOM changes, anything that can cause reflow and repaint generally.

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible that your animations *aren't* ending?

Check the documentation for the `animationcancel` event:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/animationcancel

However, it looks like browser support may be spotty (`"onanimationcancel" in HTMLElement.prototype` returns `false` for me in Chrome 67).

It seems that using a `setTimeout` hack may be necessary for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function

```js
    function onAnimationEnd(element, handler) {
        //- Create local variables
        var events = 'animationend transitionend webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend MSAnimationEnd webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd';

        //- Bind event to element
        $(element).on(events, handler)

        //- Return received element
        return element
    }
```

This function binds an event when both `animation` or `transition` ends.

Also make sure that the animated element is not being deleted or moved while the animation is running.

Comment: This is jQuery, not VanillaJS

Comment: there are still cases where this won't work, check my comment above

Answer (score 0):

With IE11, you can't necessarily assume that the JS event binding will occur before the CSS animation starts or ends. This type of issue is intermittent, and frequency/onset will depend on certain factors.

If the CSS animation-duration is low and the animation starts immediately after the stylesheet is ready, then it's possible that the JS event binding will not be applied in time

A solid workaround I've found is to use JS to invoke the CSS animation using a className. i.e., Only apply the CSS animation-name property when the className has been applied via JS.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, this is still a problem. In some cases (so far I've only reproduced it on mobile) certain elements with a well-defined animation don't always fire the `animationend` event.

**EDIT:** Turns out the issue is with animating `after` content. Safari just doesn't reliably handle it. I ended up making a distinct strikethrough div and animating that.

```
function animateCSS(element, animationName, callback) {
    const node = typeof element == 'string' ? document.querySelector(element) : element;
    node.classList.add('animated', animationName);
    node.onanimationend = handleAnimationEnd;
    console.log('animateCSS', node, animationName);

    function handleAnimationEnd() {
        console.log('handleAnimationEnd', node, 'remove:', animationName);
        node.classList.remove('animated', animationName);
        node.onanimationend = null;

        if (typeof callback === 'function') callback(node);
    }
}

.strike {
    color: #e402b3;
    position: relative;
}
.strike:after {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 2%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #e402b3;
    animation: strike 0.7s linear 0s 1 forwards;
    -webkit-animation: strike 0.7s linear 0s 1 forwards;
}
@keyframes strike {
    0% {
        width: 0%;
        color: #000;
    }
    100% {
        width: 96%;
        color: #e402b3;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes strike {
    0% {
        width: 0%;
        color: #000;
    }
    100% {
        width: 96%;
        color: #e402b3;
    }
}
```